# Jupyter requests.get returns incomplete html

Tags: python, python-requests, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I run the below python code in Jupyter notebook, but return an incomplete html.

```
import requests 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    target = 'http://www.biqukan.com/1_1094/5403177.html'
    req = requests.get(url=target)
    print(req.text)
```

Then I run it in VS code, the return is complete html

I want to know the reason, and how to return a complete html in Jupyter.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:07:29)  @jalazbe

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests 
target = 'http://www.biqukan.com/1_1094/5403177.html'
req = requests.get(url=target)
req.text
```

Try it in jupyter. Why is it? Because the mechanism in jupyter.

The reason is that there is something loaded by js. You can find something in line 53 and line 61. You can debug with Chrome, you can find

```
function read1(){
document.writeln("<div align=center style=\"margin-bottom:8px;\"><script src=\'http://www.biquge.lu/ads/kan_hf.js\'></script></div>");

}
```

You can try it by yourself, just like it.

[image]

Hope helpful.

Comment: thank you very much @pwxcoo. i am still a rookie, I will learn how to debug. now I hope to know why remove print(), just req.text can return a complete html?

Comment: @FrankYang I really want to tell you the reason. But I found something confused just now. Normally jupyter notebook is a superset of running python directly. I cannot explain it, it confused me too.